# laptop displays after 30 mins

Tags: laptop, display, gpu

I have this laptop (lenovo g555) and there is only one way to make it work.
1.Power on 2.Wait almost half an hour with black screen 3.Turn off and power on immediately 4.Lenovo boot screen appears (and laptop keeps working and displaying till you shut it down ) The only way to display to external monitor is inside windows (meaning that you need to have picture to the internal monitor to use an external, it doens't display from power on)

Comment: "*I don't want an answer like it is the motherboard because it probably is...*" Well, there is no way we could tell you with any certainty what ***exactly*** is the problem. Especially since we can not see the laptop and you haven't provided nearly enough details.

Comment: If the laptop is more than a few years old, check the CMOS battery (a button battery on the system board).  I've seen old laptops with a dead CMOS battery that wouldn't power up unless they were plugged in for a while and then restarted.

Comment: I'll give it a a try and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'll mention that unless you have a staggering amount of equipment, technical know-how, and proprietary manufacturer information; you probably can't fix a faulty motherboard even if we DID know what the problem was.

Secondly, I immediately suspect three things [in order of most to least likely]: 1) You have a faulty or otherwise corrupted display driver - try booting into safe mode and see if that affects its behaviour at all. 2) You have faulty hardware between the GPU and the monitor. Possibly replace the screen if the resources and equipment to do so are easily available. Does the laptop display when plugged into a monitor/TV via VGA or HDMI output ports? 3) Your power settings that govern when the screen shuts off automatically are seriously screwed up. Try changing the power setting plan. It's probably set to 'Balanced' now, go for any other option.

After the screen has sat dark for its ~30 minute period, the screen just pops on and begins functioning as normal, right? Indefinitely?

Comment: 1.Power on 
2.Wait almost half an hour with black screen
3.Turn off and power on immediately
4.Lenovo boot screen appears (and laptop keeps working and displaying till you shut it down )

The only way to display to external monitor is inside windows (meaning that you need to have picture to the internal monitor to use an external, it doens't display from power on)